# Jenkins always show success - TestNG, Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, testng, jenkins-plugins

I'm new with Jenkins and I have a problem with builds. I'm writing UI tests with Selenium, Java and TestNG.
My problem is that Jenkins always shows `Finished: SUCCESS` even if some tests fail.

```
    ===============================================
    TestAll
    Total tests run: 10, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
    ===============================================

    [SSH] exit-status: 0
    TestNG Reports Processing: START
    Looking for TestNG results report in workspace using pattern: **/testng-results.xml
    Did not find any matching files.
    Started calculate disk usage of build
    Finished Calculation of disk usage of build in 0 seconds
    Started calculate disk usage of workspace
    Finished Calculation of disk usage of workspace in 0 seconds
    Notifying upstream projects of job completion
    No emails were triggered.
    Finished: SUCCESS
```

How can I resolve my problem?

Comment: It's strange because Jenkins doesn't find any `testng-results.xml`. I think you should share your `pom.xml` and the mvn command run by jenkins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are building a Maven Project. 
To stop a build on test failure, go to the configure part of your project then go to the build section and in "goals & options line" add :

```
-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=false
```

this should stop the build if errors are found.